# Prove that for all values of $a$, $(a^2+a+1)x^2-2ax-a^2-1=0$ is a quadratic equation.

Tags: roots, quadratics

> Consider the equation :
>   $$(a^2+a+1)x^2-2ax-a^2-1=0$$
>   Prove that for all values of $a$, the equation is quadratic.

So I know that the coefficient of $x^2$ should not be equal to 0

$$a^2+a+1≠ 0$$
but I have no idea how to work from there.

> Without calculating the discriminant, prove that the equation (E) has two roots in R.

How do I do that ? I'm used to just calculating the discriminant and proving that it's positive which means (E) has 2 roots. What other way is there?

Comment: Discriminant of $a^2 + a + 1$ is $-3$. Therefore $a^2 + a + 1 \ne 0$ for all real $a$.

Comment: so can I just put that on the calculator (or like any other thing like it in other questions of the same type) and once I get imaginary roots then the answer would be for all real $a$ @A---B

Comment: Yes but I don't see why you need a calculator, you can calculate discriminant mentally.

Comment: yeah I know but for anything in general during exams I doubt myself so I feel like I always have to check. btw thanks @A---B

Comment: I also doubt myself on silly things like addition and multiplication in exam, lol.

Comment: ikr the silliest of things I have to check on the calculator because I feel like I might be wrong especially addition@A---B

Comment: Atleast it is a good time pass.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$a^2+a+1 = a^2 + 2(a)(1/2)+1/4+3/4 = (a+1/2)^2+3/4$$

Comment: The question is a bit weird...because doing that is what we do to get the discrimnat and the solutions of the quadratic equations...It's like reinventing the wheel each time

Answer (score 0):

In order to see if $a^2+a+1$ equals to $0$ you could try to solve:
$$a^2+a+1=0\implies a_{1,2}=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1^2-4}}{2}=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{-3}}{2}.$$

As we have $\sqrt{-3}$, we can conclude that the quadratic equation has no real roots (is not zero for $a \in \mathbb{R}$).

If you fear using the solution for the quadratic equation you can also observe that the discriminant $b^2-4ac<0$ for $ax^2+bx+c$, hence the equation has no real solution.

Answer (score 0):

In a little roundabout way:

0)$y(a) = a^3 $ is strictly monotonic in $\mathbb{R}$,

with a single, unique zero at $a=0$.

1)$y(a)=a^3-1$  is strictly monotonic $ \mathbb{R} $,

with a single, unique zero at $a=1.$

$y(a)= a^3-1=$

$ (a-1)(a^2+a+1) $.

$\rightarrow:$

$(a^2+a+1) \ne 0$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$.